# Binding and Layout relation in WPF

Tags: wpf, layout, binding

While investigating an issue with application I'm working on, I've came across one behavior I don't quite understand. It seems that when you have a TextBox (for example) with bound Text property the system takes one more layout pass than when you have a static Text.

Could anyone, please, explain why this extra pass is happening? Does the engine lay the unbound control first then binds it and then lays it once again?

To test this I've built such test case:

I've declared a class inherited from TextBox (so I can override ArrangeOverride):

```
public class MultiBoundTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TextBox.Arrange");
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
    }
}
```

Then I placed an instance of this text box in a window:

```
<local:MultiBoundTextBox x:Name="tb">
Some text
</local:MultiBoundTextBox>
```

And added some code for the window for testing:

```
    public Window11()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Window.Loaded");
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Window.Arrange");
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
    }

    private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Window.Initialized");
        tb.DataContext = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Now when I run this I get this output:

```
Window.Initialized
Window.Arrange
TextBox.Arrange
Window.Arrange
Window.Loaded
```

But if I change Text property to be bound like this:

```
    <local:MultiBoundTextBox x:Name="tb">
        <Binding Path="Day" Mode="OneWay" />
    </local:MultiBoundTextBox>
```

I get this in the output:

```
Window.Initialized
Window.Arrange
TextBox.Arrange
Window.Arrange
TextBox.Arrange
Window.Arrange
Window.Loaded
```

Notice the extra pair of TextBox.Arrange and Window.Arrange. Why is this extra pass necessary?

Comment: +1 for the detailed reproduction case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the engine lay the unbound
> control first then binds it and then
> lays it once again?

This might indeed be the case -
[WPF data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) is built heavily upon [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx), which do in fact impact the WPF layout process, see [Layout Performance Considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx#LayoutSystem_Performance):

> Dependency properties whose values can
> cause the layout system to be
> initialized are marked with public
> flags. [AffectsMeasure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.affectsmeasure.aspx) and
> [AffectsArrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.affectsarrange.aspx) provide useful clues as
> to which property value changes will
> force a recursive update by the layout
> system. In general, any property that
> can affect the size of an element's
> bounding box should set the
> [AffectsMeasure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.affectsmeasure.aspx) flag to true. For more
> information, please see [Dependency
> Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).

And specifically regarding your question see this citation from [Optimizing Performance: Layout and Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613542.aspx):

> The layout pass process is invoked again if any of the following actions occur:
>
> - [...]
> - When a change occurs to the value of a dependency property that is
>   marked with metadata affecting the measure or arrange passes.

Consequently I could imagine that the initial layout pass hasn't been considered any different from the use case of a bound value change later on, which would explain the behavior you are experiencing. While this *might* still be a missed opportunity for optimizing the startup experience, the usual optimization caveats apply: *no optimization without measurement* - e.g. this supposed redundancy (if technically avoidable at all) may have no measurable impact because the window/control has not yet been shown etc.

---

**Debugging:**

To add on Drews [suggestion of a debugging aid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734519/binding-and-layout-relation-in-wpf/1367696#1367696), there is a new dedicated debugging aid related to binding introduced in .NET Framework 3.5, see [`PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel.aspx) - example:

```
<Window ... xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase">
    <local:MultiBoundTextBox x:Name="tb">
        <Binding Path="Day" Mode="OneWay"
                 diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"/>
    </local:MultiBoundTextBox>
</Window>
```

There are some constraints for this to work though, be sure to read section *Remarks* within [`PresentationTraceSources Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel` -- that looks like it'll be useful one day.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly an answer, but what if you add a converter to the binding that doesn't do anything except write out a message that shows you at which point the binding is evaluated?

```
public sealed class LoggingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public void Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Binding.Convert");
        return value;
    }

    public void ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Binding.ConvertBack");
        return value;
    }
}
```